# Can we get an orthonormal basis for a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

By Gram-Schmidt process, we can get an orthogonal basis for such a $\mathbb{Q}-$vector space $V$. However, if we normalize each vector, the corresponding scalar may not be a rational number but a root of a rational problem. Is this a problem? Is there a way to get an orthonormal basis for $V$?

Comment: This is a genuine obstruction; it is just not true that every inner product on a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space admits an orthonormal basis, already in $1$ dimension, for exactly the reason you gave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $V:=\Bbb Q[i\pi]\subset \Bbb C$ with scalar product $\langle z,w\rangle :=\overline zw$. If $a+ib\pi$ (with $a,b\in\Bbb Q$) has length $1$, then $a^2+b^2\pi^2=1$. As $\pi $ is trancendental, we must have $b^2=0$, and then $a=\pm1$. It follows that $V$ does not admit even a *normal* basis (i.e., consisting of unit vectors that need not be orthogonal).

(You can replace $\pi$ with$\sqrt[3]2$.)

Comment: Personally I would define an inner product over a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space to take values in $\mathbb{Q}$; this is the definition that would be relevant to understanding positive-definite quadratic forms over $\mathbb{Q}$, for example.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan do you have an example of a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space with such an inner product which does not have an orthonormal basis?

Comment: @HeMan: take $\mathbb{Q}$ with the inner product $\langle x, y \rangle = 2xy$. As in Hagen's example there are no unit vectors.